# Windows batch-file output to file speed

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I typically write output to file with by redirecting output to file, such as:
`dir > output.txt`
However, this is painfully slow if I'm doing it on a large file server.
Is there a faster way to get this output to a file? or is it really just the dir command that I'm waiting for?
Thanks,

PS I also do: `tree > treeout.txt`

Edit: The full actual command is: `dir /s /q %%i:\ /a > "%save_loc%\%%i_dir_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.txt"`

So yes, it is in a for loop doing multiple drives, and does recurse subdirs, and even the owner. The largest drives will produce a 50MB text file, but it does take a very long time to generate. Just wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: 1. it is not DOS. It is Windows `cmd`. 2. How long does the command take without redirecting to file to complete? Both instances should complete in about the same time, so then there's your answer.

Comment: There is no method I know of which can enumerate a directory tree quicker than the `dir` command. As you are not using the `/S` option, or specifying specific attributes with the `/A` parameters, you are simply processing everything in one directory, and as such there is nothing in your question to suggest that your output should not happen quickly and efficiently. Your question as it currently stands cannot be reproduced unless you [edit] your question to include more details for us.

Comment: Run the command on the remote server and copy the results, that should be the fastest option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're still not showing us what your doing in-context, but no doubt you can generate a list of the appropriate drives:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "drivelist=u n"

:tmpfl
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO tmpfl) ELSE ECHO.>"%tempfile%.#"

FOR %%i IN (%drivelist%) DO (
 ECHO.>"%tempfile%.#%%i"
 START /min "drive %%i" DIR /s /q %%i:\^>"%tempfile%.%%i"^&DEL "%tempfile%.#%%i"^&cls^&exit
)
:wait
timeout /t 1 >NUL
FOR %%i IN (%drivelist%) DO IF EXIST "%tempfile%.#%%i" GOTO wait

(
FOR %%i IN (%drivelist%) DO (
 TYPE "%tempfile%.%%i"
 DEL "%tempfile%.%%i"
)
)>"u:\reportfile.txt"

DEL "%tempfile%.#"
GOTO :EOF
```

Generate a temporary filename and create `tempname.#` as a keeper.

Create `tempname.#driveletter` and `Start` a `dir` scan of every applicable drive, creating `tempname.driveletter` as a report file and deleting `tempname.#driveletter` when complete.

Wait while any `tempname.#driveletter` exists.

When no `tempname.#driveletter` exists, concatenate the `tempname.driveletter` to the reportfilename and delete it.

Result: `dir`s run in parallel so overall execution time should decrease.

Comment: Yes, I believe that will help. Esp with the `dir`s running in parallel! I'll give it a try.